# Is there a Python function like Lua's string.sub?

Tags: python, string, substring

As per the title, I am looking for a Python function similar to Lua's string.sub, whether it be 3rd party or part of the Python Standard library. I've been searching all over the internet ( including stackoverflow ) for nearly an hour and haven't been able to find anything whatsoever.

Comment: What does `string.sub` do in Lua?

Comment: Did you try: http://tinyurl.com/dyes5s

Comment: @JohnKeyes:
string.sub returns a string that has been cut from another, example:

str = "Hello, World!"
print( string.sub(str,1,5) )

Would output:
Hello

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python doesn't require such a function. It's slicing syntax supports String.sub functionality (and more) directly:

```
>>> 'hello'[:2]
'he'
>>> 'hello'[-2:]
'lo'
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnop'[::2]
'acegikmo'
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnop'[1::2]
'bdfhjlnp'
>>> 'Reverse this!'[::-1]
'!siht esreveR'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Btw, I'm just playing with it in the interpreter here.. and 'hello'[0:4] only gives me 'hell', but surely if the string begins at 0 then 4 would be the last character?

Comment: @Erkling: Slicing is inclusive on the first argument, but exclusive on the second. a[0:4] gives you elements 0 to 3.

Comment: The equivalent in function calls, if you need those instead, is: 'hello'.__getitem__(slice(1,None)) or import operator; getitem('hello', slice(1,None))

Answer (score 13):

**Lua:**

```
> = string.sub("Hello Lua user", 7)      -- from character 7 until the end
Lua user
> = string.sub("Hello Lua user", 7, 9)   -- from character 7 until and including 9
Lua
> = string.sub("Hello Lua user", -8)     -- 8 from the end until the end
Lua user
> = string.sub("Hello Lua user", -8, 9)  -- 8 from the end until 9 from the start
Lua
> = string.sub("Hello Lua user", -8, -6) -- 8 from the end until 6 from the end
Lua
```

**Python:**

```
>>> "Hello Lua user"[6:]
'Lua user'
>>> "Hello Lua user"[6:9]
'Lua'
>>> "Hello Lua user"[-8:]
'Lua user'
>>> "Hello Lua user"[-8:9]
'Lua'
>>> "Hello Lua user"[-8:-5]
'Lua'
```

Python, unlike Lua, is zero index, hence the character counting is different. Arrays start [from 1 in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785704/why-do-lua-arraystables-start-at-1-instead-of-0), 0 in Python.

In Python slicing, the first value is inclusive and the second value is exclusive (up-to but not including). Empty first value is equal to zero, empty second value is equal to the size of the string.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, python offers a (in my opinion very nice) substring option: `"string"[2:4]` returns `ri`.

Note that this "slicing" supports a variety of options:

```
"string"[2:] # "ring"
"string"[:4] # "stri"
"string"[:-1] # "strin" (everything but the last character)
"string"[:] # "string" (captures all)
"string"[0:6:2] # "srn" (take only every second character)
"string"[::-1] # "gnirts" (all with step -1 => backwards)
```

You'll find some information about it [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).